# Table Alias is Not Recognized

Tags: sql, t-sql, alias

I have some code that is creating three aliased tables (WEYellow, WEGreen, and WEPutaway) to return one table with each yellow, green, and putaway date. I get the data I need for the first two without a problem. The third table needs to use the alias of both the first and second table, but it won't recognize the second alias. I presume I'm missing something between the joins, but I don't know what.

```
SELECT 
   WEYellow.[Item No_], 
   WEYellow.[Registering Date] as [Yellow Date],
   WEYellow.[User ID] as [Yellow User],

   --GREEN DATE
   ISNULL(
    (SELECT  MIN([Registering Date]) as [GrnDate]
    FROM [Coverpools 2013 Live].[dbo].[Cover-Pools, Inc_$Warehouse Entry] as WEGreen
    WHERE WEGreen.[Item No_] = WEYellow.[Item No_] 
      AND WEGreen.[Registering Date] > WEYellow.[Registering Date] 
      AND WEGreen.[Location Code] = WEYellow.[Location Code]
      AND WEGreen.[Bin Code] = 'GREEN'
      AND [Qty_ (Base)] > 0), 
    '1900-01-01') as [Green Date],

     --PUTAWAY BIN Date
        ISNULL((SELECT MIN([Registering Date]) as [PutDate]
     FROM [Coverpools 2013 Live].[dbo].[Cover-Pools, Inc_$Warehouse Entry] as WEPutaway
      WHERE WEPutaway.[Item No_] = WEYellow.[Item No_] 
          AND WEPutaway.[Registering Date] > WEYellow.[Registering Date] 
          AND WEPutaway.[Registering Date] > WEGreen.[Registering Date] -- THIS IS THE PROBLEM
          AND WEPutaway.[Location Code] = WEYellow.[Location Code]
         --Next Bin that's not Green, Yellow, or User
         AND WEPutaway.[Bin Code] <> 'GREEN' 
          AND WEPutaway.[Bin Code] <> 'YELLOW' 
         And NOT EXISTS (Select 1 from [Coverpools 2013 Live].[dbo].[Cover-Pools, Inc_$Mobile User Setup] as MU
                                       where MU.[Short User ID] = WEPutaway.[Bin Code])
          AND [Qty_ (Base)] > 0), 
    '') as [Putaway Bin Date]


     FROM [Coverpools 2013 Live].[dbo].[Cover-Pools, Inc_$Warehouse Entry] as WEYellow
      WHERE WEYellow.[Location Code] = '01' 
            AND WEYellow.[Bin Code] = 'YELLOW'
            AND [Qty_ (Base)] > 0
```

Comment: You should add a database tag.  And, I would recommend that you simplify your query to show a more reasonable query with the problem.  I'm guessing that in the mean-time, you'll probably find the problem and can delete the question.

Comment: "The third table needs to use the alias of both the first and second table" - what are aliases of these tables?

Comment: I guess these are WEYellow and WEGreen. In my opinion WEYellow should be easily recognized, but the server won't recognize the WEGreen as it is not mentioned in the leading (underlying) FROM clause.

Comment: Just remove that line marked as THE PROBLEM? You can't access a table alias from a nested sub-query inside another nested sub-query.  I don't see what that line is trying to achieve.

Comment: `WEGreen` is an alias in your first subquery. It's not in context to use in your second subquery (your second subquery has NO idea what you mean by `WEGreen`). Instead of subquerying these in your `SELECT` clause, instead properly join these subqueries in your `FROM`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference one subquery from another subquery on the same main query.

What you can do is to create a common table expression with the main query and first subquery, and then select from it, adding the second subquery:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT 
   WEYellow.[Item No_], 
   WEYellow.[Registering Date] as [Yellow Date],
   WEYellow.[User ID] as [Yellow User],

   --GREEN DATE
   ISNULL(
    (SELECT  MIN([Registering Date]) as [GrnDate]
    FROM [Coverpools 2013 Live].[dbo].[Cover-Pools, Inc_$Warehouse Entry] as WEGreen
    WHERE WEGreen.[Item No_] = WEYellow.[Item No_] 
      AND WEGreen.[Registering Date] > WEYellow.[Registering Date] 
      AND WEGreen.[Location Code] = WEYellow.[Location Code]
      AND WEGreen.[Bin Code] = 'GREEN'
      AND [Qty_ (Base)] > 0), 
    '1900-01-01') as [Green Date],

     --PUTAWAY BIN Date
        ISNULL((SELECT MIN([Registering Date]) as [PutDate]
     FROM [Coverpools 2013 Live].[dbo].[Cover-Pools, Inc_$Warehouse Entry] as WEPutaway
      WHERE WEPutaway.[Item No_] = WEYellow.[Item No_] 
          AND WEPutaway.[Registering Date] > WEYellow.[Registering Date] 
          AND WEPutaway.[Registering Date] > WEGreen.[Registering Date] -- THIS IS THE PROBLEM
          AND WEPutaway.[Location Code] = WEYellow.[Location Code]
         --Next Bin that's not Green, Yellow, or User
         AND WEPutaway.[Bin Code] <> 'GREEN' 
          AND WEPutaway.[Bin Code] <> 'YELLOW' 
         And NOT EXISTS (Select 1 from [Coverpools 2013 Live].[dbo].[Cover-Pools, Inc_$Mobile User Setup] as MU
                                       where MU.[Short User ID] = WEPutaway.[Bin Code])
          AND [Qty_ (Base)] > 0), 
    '') as [Putaway Bin Date]


     FROM [Coverpools 2013 Live].[dbo].[Cover-Pools, Inc_$Warehouse Entry] as WEYellow
      WHERE WEYellow.[Location Code] = '01' 
            AND WEYellow.[Bin Code] = 'YELLOW'
            AND [Qty_ (Base)] > 0
)

SELECT *,
     --PUTAWAY BIN Date
     ISNULL((SELECT MIN([Registering Date]) as [PutDate]
     FROM [Coverpools 2013 Live].[dbo].[Cover-Pools, Inc_$Warehouse Entry] as WEPutaway
     WHERE WEPutaway.[Item No_] = WEYellow.[Item No_] 
     AND WEPutaway.[Registering Date] > WEYellow.[Registering Date] 
     AND WEPutaway.[Registering Date] > WEGreen.[Registering Date] -- THIS IS THE PROBLEM
     AND WEPutaway.[Location Code] = WEYellow.[Location Code]
     --Next Bin that's not Green, Yellow, or User
     AND WEPutaway.[Bin Code] <> 'GREEN' 
     AND WEPutaway.[Bin Code] <> 'YELLOW' 
     And NOT EXISTS (
         Select 1 
         from [Coverpools 2013 Live].[dbo].[Cover-Pools, Inc_$Mobile User Setup] as MU
         where MU.[Short User ID] = WEPutaway.[Bin Code]
     )
     AND [Qty_ (Base)] > 0), 
    '') as [Putaway Bin Date]
FROM CTE
```